# Issue with topic word distributions after malletmodel2ldamodel in gensim

Tags: gensim, lda, topic-modeling, mallet

After training an LDA model on gensim LDA model i converted the model to a with the gensim mallet via the `malletmodel2ldamodel` function provided with the wrapper. Before and after the conversion the topic word distributions are quite different. The mallet version returns very rare topic word distribution after conversion.

```
ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=13, id2word=dictionary)
model = gensim.models.wrappers.ldamallet.malletmodel2ldamodel(ldamallet)
model.save('ldamallet.gensim')

dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary.load('dictionary.gensim')
corpus = pickle.load(open('corpus.pkl', 'rb'))
lda_mallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet.load('ldamallet.gensim')
import pyLDAvis.gensim
lda_display = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(lda_mallet, corpus, dictionary, sort_topics=False)
pyLDAvis.display(lda_display)
```

[image: Mallet Implementation after using <code>malletmodel2ldamodel</code>]

Here is the output from gensim original implementation:

[image: Here is the output from gensim original implementation]

I can see there was a bug around this issue which has been fixed with the previous versions of gensim. I am using gensim=3.7.1

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an optional function](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2069) to use instead of malletmodel2ldamodel (reported to have bugs):

```
from gensim.models.ldamodel import LdaModel
import numpy

def ldaMalletConvertToldaGen(mallet_model):
    model_gensim = LdaModel(id2word=mallet_model.id2word, num_topics=mallet_model.num_topics, alpha=mallet_model.alpha, eta=0, iterations=1000, gamma_threshold=0.001, dtype=numpy.float32)
    model_gensim.state.sstats[...] = mallet_model.wordtopics
    model_gensim.sync_state()
    return model_gensim

converted_model = ldaMalletConvertToldaGen(mallet_model)
```

I used it and it worked perfectly.